# TinyMCE input field instead of button?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I'd like to add an input field in my TinyMCE editor instead of font size picker. This gives more options to the user, and is neater than dropdown imo.

I tried with this

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('fontsize', function(editor, url) {

    editor.addButton('fontsize', {
        text: '',
        title: 'Font Size',
        body: [
            {
                type: 'textbox',
                name: 'font_size',
                label: 'font_size',
                value: '',
                classes: 'font_size_input',
            },
        ]
    });

     editor.addCommand('fontsize', function(e) {
        var selected_text = editor.selection.getContent({
            'format': 'html'
        });
        var open_span = '<span style="font-size: '+e.data.font_size+';" data-mce-style="font-size: '+e.data.font_size+';">';
        var close_span = '</span>';
        var return_text = '';
        return_text = open_span + selected_text + close_span;
        editor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, return_text);
        return;
    });

});
```

But this gives me a button. I searched for any sign of `addInput` but I didn't find it.

Is there a made method for editor, or will I need to create a custom one to show input field (and can this be done in the first place)?